# How to select the previous element in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this html mark up:

```
<td>
    <label for="fadsf"> fadsf</label>
</td>
<td>
    <a class="editLink" href="/Admin/MenuManagement?Length=5">Edit</a>
</td>
```

What i want to do is to select the text in the label. But I find it difficult to do.

I tried this:

```
    $(".editLink").click(function () {
    alert(
     $(".editLink").prev("td").html()
     );
});
```

But it returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".editLink").click(function () {
             $(".editLink").parent().prev().find("label").html()
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`prev()` and `next()` are used for siblings. You need to find the previous `<td>`, then the label inside it:

```
$(".editLink").closest('td').prev('td').find('label')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for parent() Not prev() selecting the previous sibling where there is none in your case.

See api.jquery.com/prev/